# Why am I getting a refusal to help answer a question of mine?

Tags: discussion, moderators, community

I asked a question about getting the intimate details (well network type, what cert was used to connect to a network connection) on Windows 10. Question for context: [Replicating a wireless connection from Windows to Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1363608).

In the comment's I've had two responses:

1. I should not know those details (A bit odd for a response on SU)
2. "Because I don't know those details already and I don't have someone locally to tell me those details" then "being against the org policy/'network security'" is against "SU Policy" (This is a statement from a moderator)

Those responses make no sense to me as that 1. separate organizations. 2. the context of the question isn't about breaking into a network, it's about seeing how Windows is configured on a lower level.

Are those comments true, and is that the official stance of the site?

Comment: Often questions like these can be asked in other ways that avoids the corporate policy thing, but just as often, as we ask clarifying question, we with the knowledge will recognize that it is a corporate policy question. The thing is, even if the support staff do not appear to have the answers THEY are still the people most likely to have the answer you need (though maybe not the one you want). Also, there is either a policy saying no other computers allowed, or a process for getting computer on that network, and that's where you need to go.

Comment: Finally, many of us here on SU are IT professionals. We have high respect for our colleagues, and we know how and why organizations maintain IT policies. For this reason questions that even get close to being about circumventing existing processes are very likely to be dismissed. I am the person who answers these questions for my org, and I will not be the one to help someone else get behind their admins back.

Comment: Another possibility, nobody knows the answer to the question, you only received 2 close votes in almost 10 day timeframe.  However, you indicated you cannot provide some specific information, and that’s always frustrating as an author of an answer when I know no matter what details I ask for they cannot be provided

Answer (score 10):

See the page about what [questions you are allowed to ask](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Specifically, the section on what not to ask which includes this:

> issues specific to corporate IT support and networks

We have no way of knowing how corporate networks and environments are set up and any suggestion we make would be pure guesswork, something that we try very hard to avoid.

On top of that, what happens when you get fired for attempting any suggestions we do give you? Who is at fault there? Do we take the blame for telling you how to bypass your corporate IT security?

It's better that we eliminate any chances of causing bad situations for end users by not allowing support for these types of questions.

Answer (score 8):

> Those responses make no sense to me as that 1. separate organizations.

Employees of an organization are told system configuration information for one reason, it’s required to do your job, simply being interested in a subject doesn’t mean you have a need to know that information.

Likewise you have indicated you don’t have access to anyone who has that need to know that information.  Since you don’t seem to know enough about the organization’s network configuration, you have received close votes, for multiple reasons but primary due to the question not being within scope as defined by the help center.

Your question also asks about PEAP and TLS, since your unsure how your WPA2 Enterprise network is configured, but PEAP functions over TLS so what configuration information you want to know is actually not clear

> the context of the question isn't about breaking into a network, it's about seeing how Windows is configured on a lower level.

We are not worried about you breaking into the network, you simply don’t know enough information, to provide enough information to answer the question.  Besides you already have access to the network.

Comment: PEAP/TLS is a gap in my knowledge but according to Netmanager they ask for different pieces of information. If I knew exactly how windows was taking in information and authenticating it.. I could replicate the connection. This is not an issue for a lack of credentials.